# Empty PHP SSH2 stream contents, even with stream_set_blocking?

Tags: php, ssh, stream

I am working on a tool that reads an iptables configuration from a remote host over SSH2 using the PECL SSH2 extension. I am able to successfully make the connection to the host, authenticate, and execute commands. The trouble I am having is sometimes the stream doesn't contain any data.

```
 /**
  * Load the current firewall configuration
  * @return bool
  */
 public function loadRules() {
  $stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection,"~/iptsave;");
  stream_set_blocking($stream,true);
  $iptablesSave = stream_get_contents($stream);
  if(empty($iptablesSave)) {
   return false;
   }
  parent::restore($iptablesSave);
  return true;
  }
```

About 25% of the time, `loadRules()` returns false, even when connecting to locahost instead of the remote system. I was able to work around the problem by changing the `ssh2_exec` call to

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection,"~/iptsave; sleep .5");
```

but I am concerned that something is wrong.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

phpSecLib may be able to help:

According to [this post](http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=13223), it always returns the output, unlike ssh2.so.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue here. Somehow you need to set a delay for getting the result of the stream.

The way you've done it is possible, but you could also set a `sleep(1)` after the `stream_set_block($stream, true)` function. 
You could try the `usleep()` function. Haven't tried it yet

Comment: I thought these solutions not working but I found my mistake. I appended to end of my command "2>&1" string in order to redirect stderr to stdout. Now it works :) Please checkout this link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665041/php-why-isnt-exec-returning-output

Answer (score 0):

May be this will solve the issue:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection,"~/iptsave;");
stream_set_blocking($stream,true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$iptablesSave = stream_get_contents($stream);
```

Comment: I thought these solutions not working but I found my mistake. I appended to  end of my command "2>&1" string in order to redirect stderr to stdout. Now  it works :) Please checkout this link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665041/php-why-isnt-exec-returning-output

Answer (score 0):

With some severs you have to use 'interactive shell'. And sometimes you have to set the delay / sleep manually. A working example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($IP, 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $User, $Pass);
$cmd = "help" . PHP_EOL;
if (!$auth) {
    echo "Login Failed;
    exit(1);
}

$shell = ssh2_shell($connection);

stream_set_blocking($shell, false); // we will use manual sleep
sleep(1); // This sleep to make sure that you get the prompt back

fwrite ($shell, $cmd . ";" . PHP_EOL);
sleep(1); // This to make sure that the command executes and we get the prompt back again!
while($output = fgets($shell)){
   echo $output;
}
fwrite ($shell, "exit;" . PHP_EOL); // If needed
sleep(1);

ssh2_disconnect($connection);
unset($shell);
unset($connection);
```