# PHP - ssh2 reading output stream

Tags: php, ssh

I'm failing to display the output of an SSH stream in PHP. This is my code:

```
$output = ssh2_exec($sshCon, $sshCommand);

stream_set_blocking($output, true);

echo stream_get_contents($output);
```

The output is blank. The command is definitely running though. I also tried the solution given here: 
[Empty PHP SSH2 stream contents, even with stream_set_blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548675/empty-php-ssh2-stream-contents-even-with-stream-set-blocking)

The output should be process ID, just to let you know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec($sshCommand);
?>
```