# PHP: Why isn't exec() returning output?

Tags: php, exec, ping

I'm writing a PHP script to be used to check for network connections with Linux shell command `ping` calling it with PHP's `exec()`:

```
<?php


// Bad IP domain for testing.
$domain_bad = "lksjdflksjdf.com";

$ip_address = $domain_bad;

exec("ping -c 1 $domain_bad", $output, $return_var);

var_dump($return_var);
echo "return_var is: $return_var" . "\n";
var_dump($output);


exit;
?>
```

I'm not getting the output for the error message from ping in `$output` which is what I'm expecting:

```
$ php try.php
ping: unknown host lksjdflksjdf.com
int(2)
return_var is: 2
array(0) {
}
```

If the domain is a good domain, such as yahoo.com, then `$output` has the output from ping in an array. But if it's an error such as `'ping: unknown host lksjdflksjdf.com'` it doesn't get returned to the `$output` array.

Why is this happening and is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You should redirect stderr to stdout.

To do that, change your exec() call like this:

```
exec("ping -c 1 $domain_bad 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
```

More info about `2>&1` meaning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean).

Comment: add 2>&1 but output still is array empty, if execute from cmd , it output 2 values

Answer (score 10):

If the answer above could not solve your problem, maybe `exec()` is disabled. You can try to check `php.ini` file at `disable_functions` line.

Comment: Good hint. Should be `disable_functions` instead of `disabled_functions`