# execute windows commands in command prompt using php

Tags: php, jquery

Hello friends i am getting output of this command 
This code works perfectly

```
<?php
  echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

but problem in

```
<?php
  echo exec('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\abc\\xpdfbin-win-3.04\\bin64>pdfinfo -f 1 test.pdf');
?>
```

can you please give me your expert advice?

Comment: Can you check same command using command line?

Comment: yes its working using command line

Comment: Try using `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: I tried with "" still no output

Comment: For out put you need to   echo exec('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\abc\\xpdfbin-win-3.04\\bin64>pdfinfo -f 1 test.pdf 2>&1',$output); you get output in $output

Answer (score 1):

using `'` for the string will disable escape sequences, so either use `"` or change each `\\` to `\`

also, this might be related:
[PHP: Why isn't exec() returning output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665041/php-why-isnt-exec-returning-output)

Comment: Stil no output my friend. :(