# How to search through directory for a string

Tags: php

I've came up with a script to find a certain string in a directory, but when I do it, it only shows the first string and not the others... how would I go about it showing all of the other strings?

The code,

```
$result = exec("grep -r admin@admin.com /var/www/html/files/*");
echo $result;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `exec("grep -r admin@admin.com /var/www/html/files/*", $result);`. According to PHP manual `exec` return the last line from the result of the command

Comment: Tried that and no luck ):

Comment: @BrandonDies Did you try appending `"2>&1"` to the end of your command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665041/php-why-isnt-exec-returning-output

Comment: No, what is that?