# Show executed command and output using PHP exec()

Tags: php

I am debugging a script that is supposed to delete a file and would love to know if there is a way to echo back the command I am running along with the results:

`echo exec("rm ./" . strtolower(end(split('\/',$originalName))));`

This will return the result, but with the incoming data (which should be something like:`/plugins/Dropzone/files/xcqzr.png`) it would be great to know what exactly is getting passed into it. I know I could do it in a separate process, but wondering if there was a built in way.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16665146/7302869

Comment: You only have to store the command in a variable before exec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compose the command string beforehand and then pass it to `exec()`.

```
$command = "rm ./" . strtolower(end(split('\/',$originalName)));
echo 'Command: '.$command.PHP_EOL;
$result = exec($command);
echo 'Result: '.$result.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

try using -v with rm this should throw verbose

echo exec("rm -v ./" . strtolower(end(split('/',$originalName))));