# exec("mysqldump") returning 2 but the command works in command-line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, mariadb

I'm trying to have MySQL backup through mysqldump and the command works in the command-line but it returns 2 from exec().

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$filename = "/path/to/backup/dbBackUp".date("Y-m-d").".sql";
$backupcmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -A --single-transaction >".$filename;
exec($backupcmd, $output, $return);
```

Vardump of $output is array(0) { } and $return = 2.

Comment: Is the webserver running this?  Does the webserver user have permission for `/path/to/backup/`?

Comment: This won't fix your error, but might help you figure out what the issue is.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16665146/1007220

Comment: As @AbraCadaver said, apache is running your code (except if you're executing php /path/to/your/script.php instead of loading a web page) and it probably doesn't have permissions to read/write that folder or even to execute mysqldump

Comment: So look for the way to give your process serving php the permissions to write that folder. It depends on what system you're on (CentOS, Ubuntu, Windows etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, www-data didn't have write access to folder I was storing the backups to.  Thanks for your help.